# InteliJ: Is there a setting to always mark a directory as excluded across multiple projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Lets say there are command line tools involved and those tools always create a directory `command-line-build-dir` under `Module` directories  is there some setting to have InteliJ always set `command-line-build-dir` as `Excluded` across all my projects so I don't have to set it manually to avoid InteliJ trying to Index huge `command-line-build-dir` each time I import a new module or start a new project?

Comment: Are you using maven??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this information will help:  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-compiler-settings.html